# Update xsd after changes at structure of table

Tags: c#, xsd, datatable

I got a project where I must fix a lot of bugs, but I have a problem with changing tables.
I change type of column from nvarchar 32 to nvarchar 64, and my xsd looks still the same:

```
<xs:element name="MyTableID" msprop:Generator_UserTableName="MyTableID" msprop:Generator_RowEvArgName="MyTableIDRowChangeEvent" msprop:Generator_TableVarName="tableMyTableID" msprop:Generator_TablePropName="MyTableID" msprop:Generator_RowDeletingName="MyTableIDRowDeleting" msprop:Generator_RowChangingName="MyTableIDRowChanging" msprop:Generator_RowDeletedName="MyTableIDRowDeleted" msprop:Generator_RowEvHandlerName="MyTableIDRowChangeEventHandler" msprop:Generator_RowChangedName="MyTableIDRowChanged" msprop:Generator_TableClassName="MyTableIDDataTable" msprop:Generator_RowClassName="MyTableIDRow">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="MyTableIDID" msdata:ReadOnly="true" msdata:AutoIncrement="true" msdata:AutoIncrementSeed="-1" msdata:AutoIncrementStep="-1" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnMyTableIDID" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="MyTableIDID" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="MyTableIDIDColumn" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="MyTableID" type="xs:long" />
              <xs:element name="Type" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnType" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="Type" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="TypeColumn" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="Type">
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:maxLength value="32" />
                  </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
```

I try to update xsd in these ways:

I. 
   1. Show DataSources.

2. Click at particular .xsd and click Refresh

II. 
   1. click at designer of my xsd, at particular table.

2. Click Configure
3. Advanced options:
       Generate Insert, Update and DeleteStatements use 
       optimistic concurrency
       Refresh the datatable
4. Next, Next

   5.Finish.

And my xsd still looks the same :/ Iąm using VS 2010 Ultimate

Comment: " from nvarchar to nvarchar, and my xsd looks still the samë" - think that theres a typo here because it should look the same as you apparently havent changed anything :-)

Comment: I used brackects, and 32 and 64 were unvisible. Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed this problem:

I reply second solution, but with important solution:

First I unchecked changed column, at commandbuilder and I finished wizard

Second I check changed column at commandbuilder and I finished wizard.

Now I have

I hope this'll help some